# Get the text of all select element options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi guys i have such select element:

```
<select name='files'>
<option value='1'>logo.jpg</option>
<option value='2'>file.ex</option>
</select>
```

i would like to have an array of the items like this:

files=logo.jpg,file.ex (i want the text not the values!)

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var files = $('select[name="files"]').find("option").map(function() {
  return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

Further reading:

- [`.map()` method](http://api.jquery.com/map/)
- [`.get()` method](http://api.jquery.com/get/)